# Как правильно организовать MVP паттерн с использованием RxJava в Android?

Tags: java, android, rxjava, mvp

Здравствуйте, в MVP и RxJava я новичок. Интересует как правильно организовать работу модулей приложения с использованием паттерна MVP и RxJava2 (RxJava).

Например, у меня есть такой набор файлов:

- **ILoginPresenter** - презентер, цепляется к фрагменту.
- **ILoginInteractor** - интерактор, который выполняет бизнес логику.
- **ILoginFieldsValidation** - валидация на верность ввода текста в полях.
- **IProfileRepository** - отвечает за сохранение и загрузку данных в базе/сети
- **UserModel**

Я сейчас пытаюсь набросать эти интерфейсы и их реализовать.
1. Реализация LoginPresenter содержит CompositeDisposable.
2. Тогда по идее ILoginInteractor должен содержать методы, возвращающие Observable/Single  и т.п.
3. Допустим, мне нужно проверить поля, я делаю так:

```java
public interface ILoginFieldsValidation {
 Single<UserModel>(какой тип лучше вернуть?) isValidLoginFields(@NonNull UserModel userLoginData);
}
```

Сейчас реализация такая:

```java
 @Override
public Single<UserModel> isValidLoginFields(@NonNull UserModel userLoginData) {
    ValidationError error;
    error = isErrorValidEmail(userLoginData.getEmail());
    if (error == null)
        error = isErrorValidPassword(userLoginData.getPassword());
    if (error != null)
        return Single.error(new LoginFieldsValidationException(error.message, error.description));
    else
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> userLoginData);
}  
private ValidationError isErrorValidEmail(String email) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
            return new ValidationError("empty email", ctx.getString(R.string.login_validation_empty_email));
        if (!MyTextUtils.isValidEmail(email))
            return new ValidationError("invalid email", ctx.getString(R.string.login_validation_invalid_email));
        return null;
    }
etc..
```

4. После реализации других модулей, я в интеракторе LoginInteractor пробую реализовать цепочку:

```java
 @Override
public Single<UserModel> signin(UserModel userLoginData, boolean remember) {
    return loginFieldsValidation.isValidLoginFields(userLoginData)
            //another operators
            .flatMap(userLoginData1 -> iProfileRepository.signin(userLoginData1,remember));

}
```

Можно ли сделать красивую цепочку операторов, если модули будут возвращать не Single, а Completable (без данных) и как?

5. Что и в каком случае лучше возвращать в методах интерактора?

   ```java
   interface ILoginInteractor{
       Single<UserModel> (void/Completable?) signin(UserModel userLoginData, boolean remember);  
       Single<UserModel> (void/Completable?) signup(UserModel userRegistrationData, boolean remember);
       boolean(Completable?) isLogined(); 
       void (Completable?) logout();  
   }
   ```